# go tour when to not use pointer to struct literal in a variable

Tags: pointers, go

Per the Go [tour page 28](http://tour.golang.org/#28) and [page 53](http://tour.golang.org/#53)

They show a variable that is a pointer to a struct literal. Why is this not the default behavior? I'm unfamiliar with C, so it's hard to wrap my head around it. The only time I can see when it might not be more beneficial to use a pointer is when the struct literal is unique, and won't be in use for the rest program and so you would want it to be garbage collected as soon as possible. I'm not even sure if a modern language like Go even works that way.

My question is this. When should I assign a pointer to a struct literal to a variable, and when should I assign the struct literal itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using a pointer instead of just a struct literal is helpful when

- the struct is big and you pass it around
- you want to share it, that is that all modifications affect your struct instead of affecting a copy

In other cases, it's fine to simply use the struct literal. For a small struct, you can think about the question just as using an `int` or an `*int` : most of the times the int is fine but sometimes you pass a pointer so that the receiver can modify your int variable.

In the Go tour exercises you link to, the Vertex struct is small and has about the same semantic than any number. In my opinion it would have been fine to use it as struct directly and to define the `Scaled` function in [#53](http://tour.golang.org/#53) like this :

```
func (v Vertex) Scaled(f float64) Vertex {
    v.X = v.X * f
    v.Y = v.Y * f
    return v
}
```

because having

```
v2 := v1.Scaled(5)
```

would create a new vertex just like

```
var f2 float32 = f1 * 5
```

creates a new `float`.

This is similar to how is handled the standard `Time` struct (defined [here](http://golang.org/src/pkg/time/time.go)), which is usually kept in variables of type `Time` and not `*Time`.

But there is no definite rule and, depending on the use, I could very well have kept both `Scale` and `Scaled`.

Comment: Can you explain more when using a struct literal is more beneficial than using a pointer? I'm confused why I wouldn't just always use a pointer, or use that as the default behavior.

Comment: Sometimes you want to make it clear that a value can't be modified.  In dystroy's code above, the definition of Scaled makes it clear that there is no way that calling v1.Scaled(5) can possibly modify v1.  V1 is guaranteed to be untouched.  Sometimes the code just looks cleaner without the pointers.  Then, you have to look under the hood to appreciate this, but sometimes using structs directly will avoid allocations on the heap and manage to do more on the stack.  This can be a big win for efficiency.  Really though, in lots of cases either way will get the job done.  Don't stress over it.

Comment: @saccharine, consider reading [this article](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/_pdf/Pitfalls_of_Object_Oriented_Programming_GCAP_09.pdf) to learn how over-usage of indirection using pointers (and references -- the article talks about C++) might ruin performance. The point I want to make is that blind using of pointers to avoid copying might turn back and bite you performance-wise in some other situation.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably right that most of the time you want pointers, but personally I find the need for an explicit pointer refreshing. It makes it so there's no difference between `int` and `MyStruct`. They behave the same way.

If you compare this to C# - a language which implements what you are suggesting - I find it confusing that the semantics of this:

```
static void SomeFunction(Point p)
{
    p.x = 1;
}
static void Main()
{
    Point p = new Point();
    SomeFunction(p);
    // what is p.x?
}
```

Depend on whether or not `Point` is defined as a `class` or a `struct`.