# Pointers vs. values in parameters and return values

Tags: pointers, go

In Go there are various ways to return a `struct` value or slice thereof. For individual ones I've seen:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Val int
}

func myfunc() MyStruct {
    return MyStruct{Val: 1}
}

func myfunc() *MyStruct {
    return &MyStruct{}
}

func myfunc(s *MyStruct) {
    s.Val = 1
}
```

I understand the differences between these. The first returns a copy of the struct, the second a pointer to the struct value created within the function, the third expects an existing struct to be passed in and overrides the value.

I've seen all of these patterns be used in various contexts, I'm wondering what the best practices are regarding these. When would you use which? For instance, the first one could be ok for small structs (because the overhead is minimal), the second for bigger ones. And the third if you want to be extremely memory efficient, because you can easily reuse a single struct instance between calls. Are there any best practices for when to use which?

Similarly, the same question regarding slices:

```
func myfunc() []MyStruct {
    return []MyStruct{ MyStruct{Val: 1} }
}

func myfunc() []*MyStruct {
    return []MyStruct{ &MyStruct{Val: 1} }
}

func myfunc(s *[]MyStruct) {
    *s = []MyStruct{ MyStruct{Val: 1} }
}

func myfunc(s *[]*MyStruct) {
    *s = []MyStruct{ &MyStruct{Val: 1} }
}
```

Again: what are best practices here. I know slices are always pointers, so returning a pointer to a slice isn't useful. However, should I return a slice of struct values, a slice of pointers to structs, should I pass in a pointer to a slice as argument (a pattern used in the [Go App Engine API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.GetAll))?

Comment: As you say, it really depends on the use case. All are valid depending on the situation - is this a mutable object? do we want a copy or pointer? etc. BTW you didn't mention using `new(MyStruct)` :) But there is no difference really between the different methods of allocating pointers and returning them.

Comment: That is literally over engineering. Structs must be pretty large that returning a pointer makes your program faster. Just don't bother, code, profile, fix if useful.

Comment: There is only one way to return a value or a pointer, and that is to return a value, or a pointer. How you allocate them is a separate issue. Use what works for your situation, and go write some code before you worry about it.

Comment: BTW just out of curiousity I benchamrked this. Returning structs vs. pointers seems to be roughly the same speed, but passing pointers to functions down the lines is siginificantly faster. Although not on a level it would matter

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: I would assume that's just bc allocation is done outside the function. Also benchmarking values vs pointers depends on the size of the struct and memory access patterns after the fact. Copying cache-line sized things is as fast as you can get, and the speed of dereferencing pointers from CPU cache is much different than dereferencing them from main memory.

Comment: Your App Engine example is interesting. My answer below would suggest it should return a possibly-expanded slice like `append`. I think App Engine doesn't do that because it would have to return an `interface{}` (since the specific struct type is only known dynamically) and the designers didn't want to force the user to type-assert a returned `interface{}` back to the specific slice type because that's verbose/clunky. So it's a special situation (resizing slice + element type not known at compile time) that makes pointer-to-slice attractive there.

Comment: Related: [Why should constructor of Go return address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932822/why-should-constructor-of-go-return-address)

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer thank you for benchmarking!   So passing pointers around is faster?   I just read : https://segment.com/blog/allocation-efficiency-in-high-performance-go-services/ which says using values makes garbage collection work easier?

Comment: @Cmag it depends, also keep in mind that my answer is almost 6 years old, the runtime has changed since.

Answer (score 600, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- Methods using receiver pointers are common; [the rule of thumb for receivers is](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-type), "If in doubt, use a pointer."
- Slices, maps, channels, strings, function values, and interface values are implemented with pointers internally, and a pointer to them is often redundant.
- Elsewhere, use pointers for big structs or structs you'll have to change, and otherwise [pass values](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#pass-values), because getting things changed by surprise via a pointer is confusing.

---

One case where you should often use a pointer:

- **Receivers**  are pointers more often than other arguments. It's not unusual for methods to modify the thing they're called on, or for named types to be large structs, so [the guidance is](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-type) to default to pointers except in rare cases.

  - Jeff Hodges' [copyfighter](https://github.com/jmhodges/copyfighter) tool automatically searches for non-tiny receivers passed by value.

Some situations where you don't need pointers:

- Code review guidelines suggest passing **small structs** like `type Point struct { latitude, longitude float64 }`, and maybe even things a bit bigger, as values, unless the function you're calling needs to be able to modify them in place.

  - Value semantics avoid aliasing situations where an assignment over here changes a value over there by surprise.
  - Passing small structs by value can be more efficient by avoiding [cache misses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) or heap allocations. In any case, when pointers and values perform *similarly*, the Go-y approach is to choose whatever provides the more natural semantics rather than squeeze out every last bit of speed.
  - So, Go Wiki's [code review comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#pass-values) page suggests passing by value when structs are small and likely to stay that way.
  - If the "large" cutoff seems vague, it is; arguably many structs are in a range where either a pointer or a value is OK. As a lower bound, the code review comments suggest slices (three machine words) are reasonable to use as value receivers. As something nearer an upper bound, `bytes.Replace` takes 10 words' worth of args (three slices and an `int`). You can find [situations](https://medium.com/a-journey-with-go/go-should-i-use-a-pointer-instead-of-a-copy-of-my-struct-44b43b104963) where copying even large structs turns out a performance win, but the rule of thumb is not to.
- For **slices**, you don't need to pass a pointer to change elements of the array. `io.Reader.Read(p []byte)` changes the bytes of `p`, for instance. It's arguably a special case of "treat little structs like values," since internally you're passing around a little structure called a *slice header* (see [Russ Cox (rsc)'s explanation](http://research.swtch.com/godata)). Similarly, you don't need a pointer to **modify a map or communicate on a channel**.
- For **slices you'll reslice** (change the start/length/capacity of), built-in functions like `append` accept a slice value and return a new one. I'd imitate that; it avoids aliasing, returning a new slice helps call attention to the fact that a new array might be allocated, and it's familiar to callers.

  - It's not always practical follow that pattern. Some tools like [database interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Get) or [serializers](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) need to append to a slice whose type isn't known at compile time. They sometimes accept a pointer to a slice in an `interface{}` parameter.
- **Maps, channels, strings, and function and interface values**, like slices, are internally references or structures that contain references already, so if you're just trying to avoid getting the underlying data copied, you don't need to pass pointers to them. (rsc [wrote a separate post on how interface values are stored](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces)).

  - You still may need to pass pointers in the rarer case that you want to *modify* the caller's struct: [`flag.StringVar`](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/#StringVar) takes a `*string` for that reason, for example.

Where you use pointers:

- Consider whether your function should be a method on whichever struct you need a pointer to. People expect a lot of methods on `x` to modify `x`, so making the modified struct the receiver may help to minimize surprise. There are [guidelines](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments#Receiver_Type) on when receivers should be pointers.
- Functions that have effects on their non-receiver params should make that clear in the godoc, or better yet, the godoc and the name (like `reader.WriteTo(writer)`).
- You mention accepting a pointer to avoid allocations by allowing reuse; changing APIs for the sake of memory reuse is an optimization I'd delay until it's clear the allocations have a nontrivial cost, and then I'd look for a way that doesn't force the trickier API on all users:

  1. For avoiding allocations, Go's [escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) is your friend. You can sometimes help it avoid heap allocations by making types that can be initialized with a trivial constructor, a plain literal, or a useful zero value like [`bytes.Buffer`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer).
  2. Consider a `Reset()` method to put an object back in a blank state, like some stdlib types offer. Users who don't care or can't save an allocation don't have to call it.
  3. Consider writing modify-in-place methods and create-from-scratch functions as matching pairs, for convenience: `existingUser.LoadFromJSON(json []byte) error` could be wrapped by `NewUserFromJSON(json []byte) (*User, error)`. Again, it pushes the choice between laziness and pinching allocations to the individual caller.
  4. Callers seeking to recycle memory can let [`sync.Pool`](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/sync/#Pool) handle some details. If a particular allocation creates a lot of memory pressure, you're confident you know when the alloc is no longer used, and you don't have a better optimization available, `sync.Pool` can help. (CloudFlare published [a useful (pre-`sync.Pool`) blog post](http://blog.cloudflare.com/recycling-memory-buffers-in-go) about recycling.)

Finally, on whether your slices should be of pointers: slices of values can be useful, and save you allocations and cache misses. There can be blockers:

- **The API to create your items** might force pointers on you, e.g. you have to call `NewFoo() *Foo` rather than let Go initialize with the [zero value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value).
- **The desired lifetimes of the items** might not all be the same. The whole slice is freed at once; if 99% of the items are no longer useful but you have pointers to the other 1%, all of the array remains allocated.
- **Copying or moving the values** might cause you performance or correctness problems, making pointers more attractive. Notably, `append` copies items when it [grows the underlying array](https://blog.golang.org/slices). Pointers to slice items from before the `append` may not point to where the item was copied after, copying can be slower for huge structs, and for e.g. `sync.Mutex` copying isn't allowed. Insert/delete in the middle and sorting also move items around so similar considerations can apply.

Broadly, value slices can make sense if either you get all of your items in place up front and don't move them (e.g., no more `append`s after initial setup), or if you do keep moving them around but you're confident that's OK (no/careful use of pointers to items, and items are small or you've measured the perf impact). Sometimes it comes down to something more specific to your situation, but that's a rough guide.

Comment: What means big structs? Is there an example of a big struct and a small struct?

Comment: How do you tell bytes.Replace takes 80 bytes' worth of args on amd64 ?

Comment: The signature is `Replace(s, old, new []byte, n int) []byte`; s, old, and new are three words each ([slice headers are `(ptr, len, cap)`](http://research.swtch.com/godata)) and `n int` is one word, so 10 words, which at eight bytes/word is 80 bytes.

Comment: How do you define big structs? How big is big?

Comment: @AndyAldo None of my sources (code review comments, etc.) define a threshold, so I decided to say it's a judgment call instead of making a threshold up. Three words (like a slice) is pretty consistently treated as eligible to be a value in the stdlib. I found an instance of a five-word value receiver just now (text/scanner.Position) but I wouldn't read much into that (it's also passed as a pointer!). Absent benchmarks, etc., I'd just do whatever seems most convenient for readability.

Comment: From the first link in this answer: If the receiver is a large struct or array, a pointer receiver is more efficient. How large is large? Assume it's equivalent to passing all its elements as arguments to the method. If that feels too large, it's also too large for the receiver.

Comment: "Slices, maps, channels, strings, function values, and interface values are implemented with pointers internally, and a pointer to them is often redundant". I didn't understand this. Do you mean []*MyStruct is redundant/same as []MyStruct ? I get the difference between [] and *[] but don't understand the former.

Comment: @ozn `[]MyStruct` points to the actual array contents, so `s1 := []MyStruct; s2 := s1;` doesn't copy them -- you *don't* have to use `*[]MyStruct` to avoid the copy. `[]*MyStruct` means the array is full of many pointers to individual `MyStruct`s, which you might want (like if MyStruct is big and you're sorting the array) or might not (if MyStruct is small or you don't need to move items much). `[]MyStruct` vs `[]*MyStruct` is not always an obvious decision and the last section says more about it.

Comment: The value, completeness, insight, various scenarios and ability to communicate makes this one of the best StackOverflow responses.

Comment: *"It's not Go-y to sacrifice clean semantics for a little speed, and sometimes passing small structs by value is actually more efficient, because it avoids cache misses or heap allocations."* - Would seem to imply that more often than not, pointers were faster than passing values. My understanding is the opposite. It takes quite a large struct to make passing the value less efficient than placing it on the heap and encumbering the GC with disposing of it, whereas copying the value of something into a new stack frame is extremely fast and the value is destroyed on function return.

Comment: @FerdTurgusen I replaced the "sometimes...actually" that suggested you'd expect pointers to be faster with something trying to be neutral-ish. I think it's a little tricky to give a strong definitive answer about what's faster--factors include how often you'd be creating an alloc as opposed to passing something already allocated, whether the compiler can avoid an alloc that a pointer 'should' cause, and maybe specific numbers for your situation. Might be a fun thing to get examples/data about!

Comment: Their does not appear to be any explanation online high up in the google search results that explains what a receiver is. Their is some Kotlin page, but it is so short and generic I am fairly confidence in my assertion that that is meaningless gibberish that does not explain what it is talking about at all to anyone who does not already know what a receiver is.

It sounds like you are just using it as a synonym to func arguments, but the the tiny amount of sources online imply it is not even close to anything like that.

Comment: @Jonathon The receiver is Go methods' equivalent of 'this'/'self': https://go.dev/tour/methods/1

Answer (score 36):

If you can (e.g. a non-shared resource that does not need to be passed as reference), use a value. By the following reasons:

1. Your code will be nicer and more readable, avoiding pointer operators and null checks.
2. Your code will be safer against Null Pointer panics.
3. Your code will be often faster: **yes, faster!** Why?

**Reason 1**: you will allocate less items in the heap. Allocating/deallocating from stack is immediate, but allocating/deallocating on Heap may be very expensive (allocation time + garbage collection). You can see some basic numbers here: http://www.macias.info/entry/201802102230_go_values_vs_references.md

**Reason 2**: especially if you store returned values in slices, your memory objects will be more compacted in memory: looping a slice where all the items are contiguous is much faster than iterating a slice where all the items are pointers to other parts of the memory. Not for the indirection step but for the increase of cache misses.

**Myth breaker**: a typical x86 cache line are 64 bytes. Most structs are smaller than that. The time of copying a cache line in memory is similar to copying a pointer.

Only if a critical part of your code is slow I would try some micro-optimization and check if using pointers improves somewhat the speed, at the cost of less readability and mantainability.

Answer (score 23):

Three main reasons when you would want to use method receivers as pointers:

1. "First, and most important, does the method need to modify the receiver? If it does, the receiver must be a pointer."
2. "Second is the consideration of efficiency. If the receiver is large, a big struct for instance, it will be much cheaper to use a pointer receiver."
3. "Next is consistency. If some of the methods of the type must have pointer receivers, the rest should too, so the method set is consistent regardless of how the type is used"

Reference : https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers

Edit :  Another important thing is to know the actual "type" that you are sending  to function.  The type can either be a 'value type' or 'reference type'.

**Even as slices and maps acts as references, we might want to pass them as pointers in scenarios like changing the length of the slice in the function.**

Comment: For 2, what's the cutoff? How do I know if my struct is big or small? Also, is there a struct that's small enough such that it's **more** efficient to use a value rather than pointer (so that it doesn't have to be referenced from the heap)?

Comment: I would say the more the number of fields and/or nested structs inside, the bigger the struct is.  I'm not sure if there is specific cutoff or standard way to know when a struct can be called "big" or "large". If I'm using or creating a struct, I would know if its big or small based on what I said above. But that's just me!.

Answer (score 9):

A case where you generally need to return a pointer is when constructing an *instance* of some *stateful or shareable resource*.  This is often done by functions prefixed with [`New`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18125625/86967).

Because they represent a specific instance of something and they may need to coordinate some activity, it doesn't make a lot of sense to generate duplicated/copied structures representing the same resource -- so the returned pointer acts as the handle to the resource itself.

Some examples:

- [`func NewTLSServer(handler http.Handler) *Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewServer) -- instantiate a web server for testing
- [`func Open(name string) (*File, error)`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) -- return a file access handle

In other cases, pointers are returned just because the structure may be too large to copy by default:

- [`func NewRGBA(r Rectangle) *RGBA`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#NewRGBA) -- allocate an image in memory

---

Alternatively, returning pointers directly could be avoided by instead returning a copy of a structure that contains the pointer internally, but maybe this isn't considered idiomatic:

- *No such examples found in the standard libraries...*
- Related question: [Embedding in Go with pointer or with value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28501976)

Comment: Implicit in this analysis is that, by default, structs are copied *by value* (but not necessarily their indirected members).

Answer (score 4):

Regarding to struct vs. pointer return value, I got confused after reading many highly stared open source projects on github, as there are many examples for both cases, util I found this amazing article:
https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2014/12/using-pointers-in-go.html

"In general, share struct type values with a pointer unless the struct type has been implemented to behave like a primitive data value.

If you are still not sure, this is another way to think about. Think of every struct as having a nature. If the nature of the struct is something that should not be changed, like a time, a color or a coordinate, then implement the struct as a primitive data value. If the nature of the struct is something that can be changed, even if it never is in your program, it is not a primitive data value and should be implemented to be shared with a pointer. Don’t create structs that have a duality of nature."

Completedly convinced.