# What is the correct way to handle pointer structs in loops in Go?

Tags: pointers, struct, go

In this example on the go playground, you can see that looping over a list of objects and putting them into an array of pointer structs ends up putting the same entry into the array multiple times.

http://play.golang.org/p/rICA21kFWL

One possible solution to the issue is to make a new string and sprint the string out of the looped string into the new string.  This seems silly though.

What is the idiomatically correct way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In case I understood correctly and you simply want an array of pointers pointing to the respective string in the original array, you can always do this

```
# choose correct size from beginning to avoid costly resize
o := make([]*string, len(f))

# iterate only over index
for i := range f {
    o[i] = &f[i].username
}
```

[Here's](http://play.golang.org/p/5IJcb9_HtW) your go playground with the changes sketched out above.

Comment: This would assume that the thing I'm ranging over is indexable.  Unfortunately it isn't -- I'm pulling from a sql results object with Next().  I could dump the sql results into a regular non-pointer array first, but that also does not seem idiomatically correct.

Comment: In that case, you might have to settle with something like this: http://play.golang.org/p/ssLVP4aCsj, just copy the value you're interested in to some temp variable and take the pointer of it.

Comment: Incidentally, strings are already references to immutable data in Go, so copying them is about equally cheap if you just use a `[]string` rather than a `[]*string`. Also references: slices like `[]byte` and some other important types in Go; see http://research.swtch.com/godata for a description of some of the structures and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542989/best-practice-returning-structs-in-go/23551970 for my best go at summarizing when you should/shouldn't use pointers.