# why can't I use reflection to take the address of a slice?

Tags: reflection, go, slice

How come this works:

```
slice := make([]string, 0, 10)
sliceptr := &slice
```

this too:

```
sliceptr := &[]string{"foo","bar","baz"}
```

But this doesn't:

```
sliceaddrval := reflect.ValueOf([]string{"foo","bar","baz"}).Addr()
```

It panics with: `reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value`

---

EDIT: Overall what I'm trying to do is take a struct that is of an unknown type, make a slice of structs of that type and return a pointer to it (I'm using github.com/jmoiron/modl which requires a pointer to slice to populate with results from a SQL query).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reflect.Value` takes an `interface{}`, and an `interface{}` to a value can't be used to change the original. Otherwise, you could end up with code changing data in your `struct` when you didn't even intend to pass it a pointer. (Or, in this case, changing the length of a slice that was passed by value.) So if you take the address you'd have to do it before the `ValueOf`.

To make a pointer to a slice that you can to pass to a package that will `append` to it (like `modl` or Google App Engine `GetMulti`), you'd  use something like http://play.golang.org/p/1ZXsqjrqa3, copied here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type row struct { i, j int }

func main() {
    aRow := row{}

    valueType := reflect.ValueOf(aRow).Type()
    slicePtrVal := reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(valueType))
    slicePtrIface := slicePtrVal.Interface()

    getQueryResults(slicePtrIface)
    fmt.Println(slicePtrIface)
}

// standing in for `modl` or whatever populates the slice
func getQueryResults(slicePtr interface{}) {
    sPtr := slicePtr.(*[]row)
    (*sPtr) = append((*sPtr), row{1,3}) 
}
```

Appending to a slice in a `reflect.Value` yourself takes another few lines of `reflect`, but it sounds like the package you're working with takes care of that part for you. For general info, code to do the append is at http://play.golang.org/p/m3-xFYc6ON and below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type row struct { i, j int }

func main() {
    aRow := row{}

    // make a pointer to an empty slice
    rowType := reflect.ValueOf(aRow).Type()
    slicePtrVal := reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(rowType))
    slicePtrIface := slicePtrVal.Interface()

    // append a zero row to it
    rowVal := reflect.Zero(rowType)
    sliceVal := reflect.Indirect(slicePtrVal)
    sliceVal.Set(reflect.Append(sliceVal, rowVal))

    fmt.Println(slicePtrIface)
}
```

Comment: actually, think the correct answer is similar in spirit but slightly different (it's that an `interface{}` holding a value type can't be used like a pointer), editing

Comment: alright.  what you're saying about the slice header makes sense, i guess i just don't get what the pointer is pointing to when you do this: &[]string{} or rather why there seems to be no reflect equivalent of that.

Comment: I added a bit to the question.  Basically what I'm looking for is "make an empty slice of type X (a struct that "someone else" provides) and get pointer to it", which I need in order to collect results from a query.

Comment: Got it--about to update this to not lie about the reason it doesn't work :) then update with how to reach the more specific goal if I can.

Comment: So it turns out it's hard to get a pointer via `.Addr` even when you just created the slice (go figure), but `New()` comes to the rescue here. Updated with code.

Comment: awesome! yeah that's exactly it.