# Go: Pointer to interface{} loses underyling type

Tags: json, pointers, reflection, interface, go

I'm working with some "generic" functions in Go that operate on `interface{}` and send things around channels, etc. Slimmed down, let's say I have something like:

```
type MyType struct {
    // Fields
}

func (m *MyType) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // MarshalJSON
    log.Print("custom JSON marshal")
    return []byte("hello"), nil
}

func GenericFunc(v interface{}) {
    // Do things...
    log.Print(reflect.TypeOf(v))
    log.Print(reflect.TypeOf(&v))
    b, _ = json.Marshal(&v)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

func main() {
    m := MyType{}
    GenericFunc(m)
}
```

This outputs:

```
2014/11/16 12:41:44 MyType 
2014/11/16 12:41:44 *interface {}
```

Followed by the default `json.Marshal` output, rather than the custom one. As far as I can tell, that's because the call to `Marshal` sees a value of type pointer-to-interface rather than pointer-to-MyType.

Why do I lose type information when I take `&v`? I would expect the second line of the output to be `*MyType` and not `*interface {}`.

Is there any way for me have the custom JSON Marshaller called without explicitly casting?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a pointer to your struct and not its value to the function. The pointer is still `interface{}` but a pointer to the interface is meaningless.

Comment: In my actual code, the interface{} object comes in over a channel, so I'd prefer not to send a pointer. I'd like to retain pass-by-value semantics for the channel, in order to reduce the likelihood concurrency errors.

Comment: Your can pass channels as values and still send/receive on them.

Comment: Interface values are effectively a (type, pointer) pair (won't copy big structs), and channel values are effectively a pointer to the real structure handling the communication. You can pass both as values without trouble. See [Russ Cox's blog post describing interface values](http://research.swtch.com/godata) and [this answer on pointers versus values generally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542989/pointers-vs-values-in-parameters-and-return-values/23551970#23551970).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to send non-pointer values over a `chan interface{}` and have a custom `MarshalJSON` method work as expected. In that case, just don't define the method on the pointer type.

See [here](http://play.golang.org/p/-i2pZiBddc)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func printer(in chan interface{}) {
    for val := range in {
        buf, err := json.Marshal(val)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err.Error())
        }
        log.Println(string(buf))
    }
}

type MyType struct {
    name string
}

func (m MyType) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, m.name)), nil
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan interface{})

    go printer(ch)
    ch <- "string value"
    ch <- 25
    ch <- MyType{
        name: "foo",
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

The only real difference is the method receiver. `func (m MyType) MarshalJSON ([]byte, error)` instead of `func (m *MyType) MarshalJSON ([]byte, error)`