# Not seeing the expected side effects from goroutines

Tags: concurrency, go, append, slice, goroutine

I'm trying to get a grasp on goroutines. Take this code:

```
package main
import "fmt"

var (
    b1 []float64
    b2 []float64
)

func main() {
    go fill(&b1, 10)
    go fill(&b2, 10)

    fmt.Println(b1,b2)

    var s string
    fmt.Scanln(&s)
}

func fill(a *[]float64, n int) {
    for i:=0; i<n; i++ {
        *a = append(*a, rand.Float64()*100)
    }
}
```

As you see, I'm trying to fill two slices. But when run this way (with `go fill()`), it prints two empty slices. Why is this not working?

Comment: Any goroutine you start isn't guaranteed to finish until you wait on it with a `sync.WaitGroup`, channel, or some other mechanism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any goroutines you start aren't guaranteed to have finished (or even started!) until you've explicitly waited on them using a [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup), channel, or other mechanism. [This works](http://play.golang.org/p/noqGy-ALP8):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
)

var (
    b1 []float64
    b2 []float64
)

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    wg.Add(2)
    go fill(&b1, 10, wg)
    go fill(&b2, 10, wg)
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(b1)
    fmt.Println(b2)
}

func fill(a *[]float64, n int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        *a = append(*a, rand.Float64()*100)
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

(Just speaking of style, if it were me [I'd make this function return the enlarged slice so it's similar to `append()` itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542989/pointers-vs-values-in-parameters-and-return-values/23551970#23551970), and Go's Code Review Comments [suggest passing values](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#pass-values), though [it's not at all unconventional to extend a slice passed as a pointer *receiver* ("this") parameter](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values).)