# Go - void function and direct assignment

Tags: function, go, void, assign

I have a little problem in Go language.
I have this struct:

```
type Time struct{
    hour,min,sec int
}
```

And this function that initializes it:

```
func init_Time(t Time) (int,int,int){
    t.hour, t.min, t.sec = time.Now().Clock()
    return t.hour, t.min, t.sec
}
```

And the `main` is:

```
func main(){
   var Tm Time
   Tm.hour, Tm.min, Tm.sec = init_Time(Tm)
   fmt.Printf("Time: %d:%d:%d", Tm.hour, Tm.min, Tm.sec)
}
```

I have imported `time` package too. It works perfectly but I have 2 questions about it:

1. In my code, why is the assignment to the variables (hour,min,sec) twice done both in the `init_Time` function:

   t.hour, t.min, t.sec = time.Now().Clock()

and in the `main()`:

```
Tm.hour, Tm.min, Tm.sec = init_Time(Tm)
```

Is it necessary or is my mistake?

2. Why if I modify the `init_Time` function by transforming it into a void function, it returns values `"Time: 0:0:0"` instead of the current time?

(Example:)

```
func init_Time(t Time) {
      t.hour, t.min, t.sec = time.Now().Clock()
}
...
func main(){
     var Tm Time
     init_Time(Tm)
     fmt.Printf("Time: %d:%d:%d", Tm.hour, Tm.min, Tm.sec)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling any function (or method) and passing values makes a copy of the values, and inside the function (or method) you can only modify the *copy*. Hence if you don't assign the return values in your first example to the fields of `Time`, changes made in `init_Time()` are lost when the function returns. This also answers your 2nd question.

If you want the caller to observe the changes, you must pass a *pointer* to your value, and have the function modify the *pointed* value. In this case it is not even required to return the (modified) value:

```
func InitTime(t *Time) {
  t.hour, t.min, t.sec = time.Now().Clock()
}
```

Using it:

```
t := Time{}
InitTime(&t)
fmt.Printf("Time: %d:%d:%d\n", t.hour, t.min, t.sec)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2sUxefJj9q)):

```
Time: 23:0:0
```

(Note that the current time on the Go Playground always starts at 23:00:00.)

Also it's idiomatic to create a "constructor" like function:

```
func NewTime() *Time {
    t := &Time{}
    t.hour, t.min, t.sec = time.Now().Clock()
    return t
}
```

Using it:

```
t2 := NewTime()
fmt.Printf("Time: %d:%d:%d\n", t2.hour, t2.min, t2.sec)
```

Output is the same.

See related questions:

[Golang Operator Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040495/golang-operator-overloading/33040529#33040529)

[Copy instances of type T, when any of the methods of a named type T have a pointer receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477624/copy-instances-of-type-t-when-any-of-the-methods-of-a-named-type-t-have-a-point/41482152#41482152)