# Why would you return a pointer to a newly created struct in Go?

Tags: pointers, go, struct, constructor

A lot of examples out there (like [this](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals)) show something like:

```
type person struct {
    name string
    age int
}

func NewPerson(n string, a int) *person {
    p := person{n, a}
    return &p
}
```

Whilst I'm comfortable with the mechanics of the above, there seems to be an idiom of always returning a pointer to the new struct.

Why wouldn't you simply **always** return the actual struct itself, rather than a pointer to it?

The struct is small, and future mutability doesn't come into it as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542989). Also, that question doesn't specifically address the constructor idiom. Is it all about perceived efficiency and memory?

Comment: Please explain to me why this is a duplicate

Comment: @JimB your dupe hammer is friendly challenged. I assume the both of you manage to work this out in an orderly manner?

Comment: The actual determinant for returning a pointer or not is dependent on the context, and sometimes just personal preference. The _reasons_ you may choose one over the other are clearly laid out in the duplicates. The reasons why you could always return a struct value _in this particular case_  are covered as well. Seeing how there are many cases where you need to use a pointer, the additional question of "why can't I always not use a pointer" doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: After reading the answers to the two duplicates, what questions remain?