# How to use the error interface

Tags: go

I have source like the following:

```
type Record struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Service string `json:"service"`
    Success bool   `json:"success"`
    Error   string `json:"error"`
}

func (zp *Zephyr) Write(err ...*error) {

    if len(err) > 0 {
        errPtr := err[0]
        if errPtr != nil && *errPtr != nil {
            // error occurred, set success to false and Error to the error message
            zp.Success = false
            zp.Error = errPtr
        } else {
            zp.Success = true
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is how can I access the string that is embedded in `errPtr`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointers vs. values in parameters and return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542989/pointers-vs-values-in-parameters-and-return-values)

Comment: Thanks to all for the down votes, your insightful comments have been most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you likely don't want `*error`, you most likely just want `error`; pointers to interfaces are very seldom the correct choice.

Second, there isn't necessarily a `string` embedded in an `error`. The [definition of `error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error) is nothing more than:

```
type error interface {
        Error() string
}
```

Meaning if you call the `Error()` method, it will return a string, but it may be generated every time the method is called; it's not necessarily a string field in the error object.

Most likely, what you want is something like this:

```
func (zp *Zephyr) Write(err ...error) {

    if len(err) > 0 {
        errPtr := err[0]
        if errPtr != nil {
            // error occurred, set success to false and Error to the error message
            zp.Success = false
            zp.Error = errPtr.Error()
        } else {
            zp.Success = true
        }
    }
}
```

If you can't change the signature, you just need to dereference the pointer:

```
zp.Error = (*errPtr).Error()
```

Playground example here: https://play.golang.org/p/dxT108660l

Errors are also covered in [the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/19).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - the code above is what I have to work with - so I can't change from *error to error.  I have already tried errPtr.Error() and that doesn't work (unresolved reference 'Error')

Comment: And that's the answer (dereferencing pointers) - thanks a bunch!