# Confusion between Pointer or No Pointer for Nested array struct

Tags: pointers, go, struct, nested

I have read some of the stack overflow question related to "why pointer and why not pointer", but I could not understand much.

So, want to understand based on my example below

I have a list of users and I am finding a hard time to understand which approach is better and faster for the purpose of nesting array struct of users inside another struct.

For an example -

```
type loc struct {
    Type string
    Point []float64
}

type User struct {
    ID string
    Name string
    Location loc
    ... // 30 more fields
}
```

**Case A - Using pointer for nested array struct**

```
type Games struct {
    ID string
    Owner []*User
    Player []*User
}

// and storing it as

G:= Games{
    ID: "1",
    Owner: []*User{
        &User {
            ID: "2",
            Name: "User A",
        },
    },
}
```

**Case B - Should I use above approach or below approach to**

```
type Games struct {
    ID string
    Owner []User
    Player []User
}

// storing it as

G := Games {
    ID: "1",
    Owner: []User{
        {
            ID: "2",
            Name: "User A",
        },
    },
}
```

Considering the situation, I do not have to change data for `Owner` or `Player` after creating value for `Games` above and **`Player` can sometimes remain Nil**, should I use only `User` or it's better to use `*User`

I  have following confusion based on above 2 cases

- Performance - which one is better & why?
- Garbage Collection - which one is better & why?
- Any Memory effects?
- Any other effects!

### Please help me out understanding based on the above example, which method would you have chosen above and why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23551970/2100197

Comment: I read that and I can understand is there is no point using "pointer" in my use case above. it is perfect to go with Case B.

Comment: All your question do not have answers: They all depend on other things than pointer vs- non-pointer. If all your method are on *User you probably want to store *Users. For all the "performance" related questions: Measure your actual use case and decide.

Comment: There is no method where the struct is used as pointer or reference. Everything is stored straight away to database after providing value to the struct.  That is why, I mentioned to answer based on above situation without assuming anything extra.

Comment: Okay, so just runtime performance and amount of generated garbage: Measure! Thats why you got tools to do so. There is no sense in guessing or asking (on SO or somewhere other): Measure your specific case!

Answer (score 0):

use option B

but if you want avoid allocation during iterations or change the content, you need to do it like this:

```
 for i:=range G.Games{
       G.Games[i]....
 }
```

this way a copy will be created in every iteration

```
for _,game:=range G.Games{
      game....
 }
```

this looks like premature optimization.
write in the most simple/readable way and if is not fast enough, take a look at [this](https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) in order to find the bottleneck