# Pointer vs value receiver in Go | heap.Interface vs sort.Interface

Tags: pointers, go

I came across priorityqueue example under heap.Interface package

Link: https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#Interface

For `Push()` and `Pop()` function required by `heap.Interface`, the implementation is on pointer receiver. But for `Swap()` function required by `sort.Interface`, the implementation is on value.

Why this difference ?

As per my understanding, `Push()` and `Pop()` are implemented on pointer type, as they need to change the underlying data. But going by that logic, `Swap()` should also be implemented on pointer type.

How and why does the `Swap()` implementation work on value, but `Push()` and `Pop()` do not ?

Answer (score 2):

A pointer receiver is needed when the value passed needs to be modified. In the case of `Swap`, the value itself (which is a slice) doesn't get modified, although the array backing the slice does get modified.

In the case of `Push` and `Pop`, the slice *does* get modified since in both cases the length changes (and in the case of `Push` the underlying array may get replaced by a new one if it has reached its capacity).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `Push` implementation:

```
func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    n := len(*pq)
    item := x.(*Item)
    item.index = n
    *pq = append(*pq, item)  // Here, the slice is assigned a new value
}
```

`Push` (and `Pop`) modify the underlying slice as well as the slice elements for the priority queue, whereas `Swap` will only swap two elements in the slice, and will not change the slice itself. Thus, `Swap` can work with a value receiver.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, a slice variable holds a length, a capacity, and a pointer to the data. Swapping items changes the data, but doesn't change any of the items in the slice header. Russ Cox [explained this in a blog post](https://research.swtch.com/godata).

Adding items to the slice, like to push something onto a heap, may require the array to be re-allocated, which will change the capacity and the location that needs to be pointed to.

You may find [this answer on pointers vs. values generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542989/pointers-vs-values-in-parameters-and-return-values/23551970#23551970) to be useful. There are other types, like channels and maps, that contain references such that you don't need a pointer to mess with the data underneath.